# Aframe Kinematic Body / Static body don't work

Tags: html, aframe

I'm facing issues concerning the kinematic body of aframe.

[image]

I put static-body in different a-box a-torus and Obj and I can still go through them. I've attached a kinematic body composent on my camera so i don't know what's going on. (i've attached the aframe-physics-system script to it)

Do you have any clues ?

Thanks a lot

```html
<a-scene physics="debug: true">

    <a-entity  camera look-controls wasd-controls position="0 2 0" jump-ability kinematic-body></a-entity>
     
     <a-box static-body scale="1 10 40" position="10 5 0" rotation="0 0 0" visible="true" material="" geometry="primitive:box"></a-box>
     <a-torus static-body scale="1.5 1.5 2" position="6.2 .75 1.16" rotation="90 0 0" visible="true" material="src:#jean; reflectivity:0.5; roughness:1"></a-torus> 
<a-torus static-body scale="1.5 1.5 2" position="6.2 .75 5.36" rotation="90 0 0" visible="true" material="src:#jean3; reflectivity:0.5; roughness:1"></a-torus>
<a-torus static-body scale="1.5 1.5 2" position="6.2 .75 9.6" rotation="90 0 0" visible="true" material="src:#jean2; reflectivity:0.5; roughness:1"></a-torus>
<a-obj-model static-body src="#table-obj"  material="src:#dark_wood" scale=".03 .03 .03" position="0 1.02 15.44" rotation="0 0 0" ></a-obj-model>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `kinematic-body` component isn't compatible with `wasd-controls`, which essentially lets the camera go wherever it wants. The controls need a concept of 'velocity' so that (1) collisions can be detected frame-by-frame, and (2) the `kinematic-body` component can modify velocity according to collisions.

To support all of that, you will need to use the [`universal-controls` component](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls). This component is a replacement for both `wasd-controls` and `look-controls`, so it should be used simply as:

```
<a-entity camera universal-controls position="0 2 0" jump-ability kinematic-body></a-entity>
```

Another important note: The `kinematic-body` component does not support roomscale VR locomotion.